# Xamarin Forms - App open from push notification - Bound property changed has no effects

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms, push-notification, system.reactive, scheduling

I have a `ViewModel` that listens for push notifications and set a bool to true when it receives one. When that bool is true, an icon in the corresponding view turns red.

When the app is in the foreground and receives a push, it works as expected. However, when the app is in background and open through the notification the icon colors doesn't change.

Here the code:

```
Disposables
    .Add(pushService
         .NewMessage
         .SubscribeOn(_schedulerProvider.Background)
         .ObserveOn(_schedulerProvider.Foreground)
         .Subscribe(_ => HasNewMessages = true, LogError));
```

In an attempt in trying to understand what was going on I did:

```
Disposables
    .Add(pushService
         .NewMessage
         .SubscribeOn(_schedulerProvider.Background)
         .ObserveOn(_schedulerProvider.Foreground)
         .Subscribe(async _ => 
         {
             await _navigationService.DisplayAlert("push", "push", "ok");
             HasNewMessages = true;
         }, LogError));
```

Sure enough now when the app is in background and open through the notification there is an alert and the icon turns red.

UPDATE

I thought that maybe, for reasons I couldn't understand, when the app was open from a notification the observation for the event wasn't happening on the UI thread so I tried the following but of course that wasn't the problem.

```
Disposables
    .Add(pushService
         .NewMessage
         .SubscribeOn(_schedulerProvider.Background)
         .Subscribe(_ => Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => HasNewMessages = true), LogError));
```

Also, note that once the app was open through a notification, it doesn't "react" on notification anymore when in foreground.

Comment: What does the property `HasNewMessages` look like? Are you firing the `PropertyChanged` event on your ViewModel when  `HasNewMessages` gets updated?

Comment: The binding is fine (it's one of a millions in the app ;-) ).

Comment: Ah okay. I figured that was the case, couldn't hurt to ask though.

Comment: I sense it's related to app lifecycle and subscription being disposed or suspended or somehting around these concepts.

Answer (score 0):

The code is my question is fine.
The issue was with:

```
protected override void OnResume() { ImageService.Instance.SetExitTasksEarly(false); }
```

My icon (the one that is supposed to turn red) is an Svg from (the great) [FFImageLoading](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading) and the above call was preventing it (somehow) from changing color. Once I removed that override, everything worked as expected.